# How to loop on python all script?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this simple script for the game Rock-paper-scissors, but I don't know how to loop the game so it doesn't end and the person keeps playing by choosing y or n.

I try some kindoms like writing a new input but this cause errors.
I try `while True:` on initial and end of script
I try `start()`
Help me pls! I gave you a cookie! :
I'm using Pycharm program to write the commands!

this is my script (i'm studying python and it was done with the help of the internet)

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
itens = ('Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura')
computador = randint(0, 2)
print('''Suas opções:
[ 0 ] PEDRA
[ 1 ] PAPEL
[ 2 ] TESOURA''')
jogador = int(input('Qual é a sua escolha? '))
print('JÔ')
sleep(0.5)
print('KEN')
sleep(0.5)
print('PÔ!!!')
print('-=' * 15)
print('O computador escolheu {}'.format(itens[computador]))
print('Jogador escolheu {}'.format(itens[jogador]))
print('-=' * 15)
if computador == 0: # computador jogou pedra
    if jogador == 0:
        print('EMPATE')
    elif jogador == 1:
        print('Jogador GANHOU!')
    elif jogador == 2:
        print('Computador GANHOU!')
    else:
        print('Jogada inválida!')
elif computador == 1: # computador jogou papel
     if jogador == 0:
         print('Computador GANHOU!')
     elif jogador == 1:
         print('EMPATE')
     elif jogador == 2:
         print('Jogador GANHOU!')
     else:
         print('Jogada inválida!')
elif computador == 2: # computador jogou tesoura
    if jogador == 0:
        print('Jogador GANHOU!')
    elif jogador == 1:
        print('Computador GANHOU!')
    elif jogador == 2:
        print('EMPATE')
    else:
        print('Jogada inválida!')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

Place the entire code in a function, and create a while loop. For example:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def loop():
*** your entire game here ***

reply = "y"
while reply == "y":
    loop()
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I started studying python just three days ago, I don't know much about programming language, any type, but I'm enjoying learning python, I'm thinking about the future and the possibilities of programming that way. def loop (): on initial code and reply = "y" at the end?

Comment: "C:/Users/André/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmEdu2020.1/scratches/Games/JO KEN PO.py", line 50, in <module>
    while reply == 'y':
NameError: name 'reply' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def loop():
itens = ('Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura')
computador = randint(0, 2)
print('''Suas opções:
[ 0 ] PEDRA
[ 1 ] PAPEL
[ 2 ] TESOURA''')
jogador = int(input('Qual é a sua escolha? '))
print('JÔ')
sleep(0.5)
print('KEN')
sleep(0.5)
print('PÔ!!!')
print('-=' * 15)
print('O computador escolheu {}'.format(itens[computador]))
print('Jogador escolheu {}'.format(itens[jogador]))
print('-=' * 15)
if computador == 0: # computador jogou pedra
    if jogador == 0:
        print('EMPATE')
    elif jogador == 1:
        print('Jogador GANHOU!')
    elif jogador == 2:
        print('Computador GANHOU!')
    else:
        print('Jogada inválida!')
elif computador == 1: # computador jogou papel
     if jogador == 0:
         print('Computador GANHOU!')
     elif jogador == 1:
         print('EMPATE')
     elif jogador == 2:
         print('Jogador GANHOU!')
     else:
         print('Jogada inválida!')
elif computador == 2: # computador jogou tesoura
    if jogador == 0:
        print('Jogador GANHOU!')
    elif jogador == 1:
        print('Computador GANHOU!')
    elif jogador == 2:
        print('EMPATE')
    else:
        print('Jogada inválida!')
reply = "y"
while reply == "y"
loop()
```

>

```
     PyDev console: starting.
>     Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>     runfile('C:/Users/André/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmEdu2020.1/scratches/Games/JO
> KEN PO.py',
> wdir='C:/Users/André/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmEdu2020.1/scratches/Games')
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>       File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Edu 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
>         pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
>       File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Edu 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>         exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>       File "C:/Users/André/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmEdu2020.1/scratches/Games/JO
> KEN PO.py", line 5
>         itens = ('Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura')
>         ^
```

I don't know why I'm giving an error! Maybe I have to download a library?